# What determines the rendering order of adjacent templates in alpine.js?

Tags: alpine.js

I have two adjacent templates that produce table rows in a table.  However, the second template's table rows are always rendered first/earlier in the table?   What are the precedence rules for rendering these templates?

```
            <template x-for="..."> //template 1
                <template x-if="...">
                    <tr>
                     ...
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template x-for="..."> //template 2 always renders first in <tbody>
                <tr>
                ...
                </tr>
            </template>
```

Comment: It might be because the first *x-for* contains an *x-if*. Anyway I suggest you to change approach and use a single  *x-for* for everything. Having some additional details the answer could be more precise

Comment: @Pippo thanks. I had to make them in parallel because the rows themselves are fairly unrelated.  I'll break down that clause to see if that's it.

Comment: @Pippo I found it wasn't rendering in order because of an unrelated syntax error. Sorta strange but once that js error was fixed I could move the templates around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an unrelated JS syntax error where the byproduct rendered the templates out of order.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for):

> `x-for` MUST be declared on a `<template>` element That `<template>` element MUST contain only one root element

This single root cannot be a `<template>` tag (as described [here](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/158#issuecomment-606128323)).

To me it seems your data wouldn't properly render to begin with.